# нет папки /var/www/ после установки lamp

Tags: linux, apache2, lamp

установил сервер командой `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`, и читая мануалы, часто набредаюсь на папку `/var/www/`, но в моей системе этой папки не существует. Адрес "localhost" функционирует, то есть установка успешна. Но  не могу понять, как создавать сайт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз tasksel - значит, скорее всего, debian-based.
Раз debian-based - значит, вероятно, /etc/apache2. Правильный метод - читать apache2.conf / httpd.conf и разбираться в его "Include", быстрый - заглянуть в /etc/apache2/sites-enabled и поискать в тамошних файлах директиву DocumentRoot. Она и будет показывать на путь к корню вашего сайта.

Можно ещё проще:

```
cd /etc
grep -R -i documentroot *
```

Comment: я уже читал и там указан этот путь. Но сам не догадался его создать. Я создал. Но теперь стоит вопрос, а как создавать несколько сайтов? Есть ли способ несколько проектов делать? Я, как человек, избалованный денвером, привык к такому

Comment: Конечно, есть. Через настройку множественных VirtualHost.
Но эта тема имеет весьма малое отношение к первоначальному вопросу.

Comment: спасибо, хоть дали направление

Answer (score 1):

Видимо ваша система использует другую папку для хранения файлов сайта. Посмотреть можно в /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
Ну и потом никто не мешает создать эту папку самому и в последиствии настраивать ваш apache на работу с этой папкой

```
mkdir /var/www/
chown apache2:apache2 /var/www/
```

Comment: Для Капитана Флинта. Объясняю, почему я отклонил предлагаемую правку. Не на всех линукс системах запуск идёт от www-data, иногда и от apache или apache2. В вопросе не было прописано, какой дистрибутив -- и поэтому вы вольны гадать в собственном ответе -- но править чужой ответ несколько неэтично. "Предлагаемая правка нисколько не улучшает ответ".